# What is the best approach to a "filter-fork"?

Tags: git, github

I've used filter-branch in the past, but now I'm looking for a solution to expose a private repository's folder by forking it to allow me and others to create pull requests.

Say I have project A and project A has folderA, I need to create a fork B from A that only contains folderA in it.

What is a good way to do this? I can't find an easy solution without forking the entire repository and then applying a filter-branch.

Edit: the fork will be **public**

Thank you :)

Comment: Well, I would use `git submodule` for the problem. Regarding the _previous_ history of `folderA` you should decide whether you actually need to expose history of changes in `folderA` to others. If you do, then you should `filter-branch` them, but most likely you may consider the moving of `folderA` to a separate git repo and attaching it to project A as a submodule be a day 0 for the outside world

Comment: If you need further explanations, I could create a more elaborate answer, but basically the idea is on the table already.  Also you could try a beast called subtree merge, but in practice it's more cumbersome.

Comment: if I fork that other project than filter branch master, will people still be able to see some kind of history anywhere in the repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several possibilities.

1. submodule without prior history
   In this case you should take your *current* state of `folderA` i.e. recursively copy it to an external subdirectory. Then run `git init` in that subdirectory, publish as usual the newly created repository on github. Then you need to remove the content of `folderA` from your project (`git rm -rf folderA`) and then re-attach it as a git submodule (see [this tutorial](https://chrisjean.com/git-submodules-adding-using-removing-and-updating) for example) and then commit your changes to the main project.

In this case your external users won't know that folderA had some prior history at all, but certainly, starting from this "day 0" `folderA` will have its own history and you can track it in your shell project.

2. git submodule with complete prior history. In this case you need to filter your existing repository. Upon filtering you form a new history for the `folderA` by selecting only folderA content and only relevant changesets and in same time replace `folderA` *directory entry* with an entry of the special type called [gitlink](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fast-import.html#_tt_filemodify_tt) (actually `gitlink` is simply an arbitrary SHA-1, `git submodule` uses it to refer revisions in a "foreign repository".

I couldn't call this method easy but it's doable indeed and if you really need to expose `folderA` prior history, it's the way to go.

3. [git subtree merge](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging) Although nowadays I'm not a big fan of this method (git submodule seems to be a more convenient generic solution), it's still possible to filter folderA into a completely independent sequence of changesets as in p.2 and then merge the shell project with changes in `folderA` using this type of merge. Likely you won't find this way convenient, but it's possible nevertheless and sometimes useful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an "easy solution" to this problem that's any better than the one you proposed (fork/filter-branch). Git is not like SVN, it does not support "sparse clones" (partial clones of a repository).